# jquery-mobile multi-column layout possible using grids?

Tags: jquery-mobile, multiple-columns

I'm trying to get a multi column layout working using Jquery Mobile.

First I tried using Jquery Mobile Grids. Example can be found here: 
[link text](http://www.franckreich.de/GP/members/demo2.html)

Since this didn't work, I tried to workaround using plain Jquery and JqueryMobile. Example here:
[link text](http://www.franckreich.de/GP/members/demo.html)

even worse...

Question: 
When a link is clicked, is there a way to only update the middle grid using Jquery Mobile = left and right content AND header should stay (persistent)? 
If there isn't, what would be a "working workaround"

Thanks for help,

Regards,

Frequent

**EDIT 2011-11-24:**
I'm setting up my own JQM plugin for multi-panel and popup-panel layouts. See [Github](https://github.com/frequent/multiview)

Comment: I've seen a two column layout on a screenshot somewhere, so it should be possible, but I havent seen any info about it in docs or tutorials. I will try to look into it. Please post your findings here.

Comment: Ok, found it - it's in an old post on the qjuerymobile blog: http://blog.jquery.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/jquerymobile.png but I don't think it was a screenshot... Might be just a picture.

Comment: I have found this link, which shows a nice example, but also just a picture. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ipad-layouts

Comment: Here is a dual-column plugin that is helpful: http://asyraf9.github.com/jquery-mobile/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Idea 3**
jQuery Mobile links to 2 different solutions that work with current version. See:

*[edit] doesn't work with current version anymore. I'm considering getting back to the game and creating something from scratch*
http://asyraf9.github.com/jquery-mobile/

or

http://www.stokkers.mobi/valuables/multiview/page2.html

**Idea 2**

Plugging into page* events.

*not avaliable anymore*
http://jquerymobiledictionary.dyndns.org/dualColumn.html

The version 0.2 was released. Plugin now works without any JS coding.

**Idea 1**

*.page() is obsolete, but the main idea should still work with .trigger('create')*

My first idea that will work with current jQuery Mobile is to never use default methods of loading the content.

This way you will create a grid of your liking and load content via your ajax calls, put loaded data in chosen containers (MUST wrap data with a container that is newly inserted into DOM) and call `.page()` on it. see: http://jquerymobiledictionary.dyndns.org/faq.html

This will work, but will not ever be usable by non-javascript browsers. So it messes the whole progressive enchancement of jQuery Mobile. This shouldn't happen if you plan on creating a real-life application. I did such a thing in my jqureymobiledictionary page (dictionaries are loaded via ajax, inaccessible if one has JS turned off). The main purpose was to keep dictionaries in JSON format though. I don't recommend it for an application that doesn't have developers as a main target :)

Comment: Curious regarding idea 2. I will check #1 in the meantime. THANKS so far. Frequent

Comment: A "changeGrid" function alongside the changePage function supplied by Jquery Mobile would be nice.

Comment: GREAT! Thanks a lot. Could be just what I've been looking for.

Comment: Thanks for starting me up on this problem. it was fun to do :) Mail me bugs and ideas - my adress is in the about page.

Comment: Sure. It's just that it was sunday. ;)

Comment: [http://asyraf9.github.com/jquery-mobile/](http://asyraf9.github.com/jquery-mobile/) doesn't seem to be compatible with latest JQM version. Is it?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it's not compatible. The author provides a copy of JQM to work with. That's lame...